# How to make cargo doc include information what feature is required for code to be included?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Do you know how to make `cargo doc` document nicely what features are required for some code to be included / work? Much like this example from `tokio`:

[image]

How should I annotate my code? What arguments should I pass to `cargo`? I want to include documentation like this in my own crate, but all attempts I made failed.

Comment: Tokio is open source, which means you can [look to see how they implemented it](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/tokio-0.2.22/tokio/src/macros/cfg.rs#L228-L236).

Comment: Tokio is also quite complex project and I spent some time looking it up, but I didn't know what to look for exactly. Thank you regardless.